# reproduce data grid structure with push

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, push

I got this structure to set up my data grid

```
var gridStructureVK4000 = [{
                    cells : [
                        [{

                                field : "Datum",
                                name : "Datum",
                                //width : "12.5%",
                                styles : 'text-align: center;'
                            }, {
                                field : "VERSENDET_PDF",
                                name : "VERSENDET_PDF",
                                //width : "15%",
                                styles : 'text-align: center;'
                            }, {
                                field : "FAKTUREN_POSTBILLING",
                                name : "FAKTUREN_POSTBILLING",
                                //width : "15%",
                                styles : 'text-align: center;'
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ];
```

but I want to build this structure by my own over the "push" function to make my code more flexible. This is what I got so far:

```
var gridStructureVK4000 = {
                cells : []
            };

for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {

                gridStructureVK4000.cells.push({
                    field   : metricNames[i-1],
                    name    : metricNames[i-1],
                    styles : gridStyle
                });
                }
            }
```

Can anybody help me reproduce the structure over the push statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `push` statement with

```
gridStructureVK4000.cells = [];

gridStructureVK4000.cells[0].push([{
                    field   : metricNames[i-1],
                    name    : metricNames[i-1],
                    styles : gridStyle
                }]);
```

Basically your `cells` array has an array